# Ruby on Rails: How best to escape a string in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, sanitize

I want my application to sanitize html on input rather than on display, so that the fields saved into the database are sanitized.

I've been doing this with `strip_tags`, and it was working great. However, this has the downside that it means the user can't input anything that's bracketed with `<` and `>`.

How can I tell Rails in the model to securely escape tags before saving them to the database? I'd like to not have to call `h` on the sanitized fields again before using them in the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `h` method in a `before_save` filter.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the plugin xss_terminate: http://code.google.com/p/xssterminate/

By default it strips all HTML tags from user input.